# Test of unique-ness

Tags: inference, small-sample

I have a sample of 20 drugs defined by about 30 parameters. I would like to run a "unique-ness" test to see whether one of the drugs is unique in any way relative to the other 19 parameters. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Because "unique in any way" is so broad and vague, would you please edit your question to be more specific?  Indeed, could you also describe what a sample of drugs might be?  A subset of them, or measurements of the parameters on instances of each of them, or something else?